# Valgrind errors from boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost-asio, valgrind

I came across strange errors reported by valgrind when analyzing my program. Could you help me to find their source?

**Minimal example**

main.cpp:

```
#define BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING

#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service ioService;
    Foo foo(ioService);
    ioService.run();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

foo.h:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

class Foo
{
private:
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver_;

public:
    Foo(boost::asio::io_service & ioService);

    virtual ~Foo()
    {}
};
```

foo.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"

Foo::Foo(boost::asio::io_service & ioService) : resolver_(ioService)
{
}
```

When compiled with `g++ -g3 -O0 -lboost_system -lpthread -o main ./main.cpp ./foo.cpp` and executed with `valgrind ./main` valgrind reports [5 errors](https://pastebin.com/AHnewNs7) of type invalid write.

```
==14905== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==14905== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==14905== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==14905== Command: ./main
==14905== 
==14905== Invalid write of size 1
==14905==    at 0x406724: boost::asio::detail::scheduler::scheduler(boost::asio::execution_context&, int) (scheduler.ipp:103)
==14905==    by 0x40CBF6: boost::asio::io_context::io_context(int) (io_context.ipp:44)
==14905==    by 0x40CE22: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service_base::resolver_service_base(boost::asio::io_context&) (resolver_service_base.ipp:40)
==14905==    by 0x40DC6A: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::resolver_service(boost::asio::io_context&) (resolver_service.hpp:58)
==14905==    by 0x40DA56: boost::asio::execution_context::service* boost::asio::detail::service_registry::create<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>, boost::asio::io_context>(void*) (service_registry.hpp:87)
==14905==    by 0x40C88F: boost::asio::detail::service_registry::do_use_service(boost::asio::execution_context::service::key const&, boost::asio::execution_context::service* (*)(void*), void*) (service_registry.ipp:132)
==14905==    by 0x40D86D: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>& boost::asio::detail::service_registry::use_service<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >(boost::asio::io_context&) (service_registry.hpp:39)
==14905==    by 0x40D6A0: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>& boost::asio::use_service<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >(boost::asio::io_context&) (io_context.hpp:39)
==14905==    by 0x40D596: boost::asio::basic_io_object<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>, true>::basic_io_object(boost::asio::io_context&) (basic_io_object.hpp:224)
==14905==    by 0x40D498: boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::basic_resolver(boost::asio::io_context&) (basic_resolver.hpp:101)
==14905==    by 0x40C544: Foo::Foo(boost::asio::io_context&) (foo.cpp:3)
==14905==    by 0x402D79: main (main.cpp:10)
==14905==  Address 0x5f06110 is 0 bytes after a block of size 240 alloc'd
==14905==    at 0x4C2E94F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14905==    by 0x40CBE1: boost::asio::io_context::io_context(int) (io_context.ipp:44)
==14905==    by 0x40CE22: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service_base::resolver_service_base(boost::asio::io_context&) (resolver_service_base.ipp:40)
==14905==    by 0x40DC6A: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::resolver_service(boost::asio::io_context&) (resolver_service.hpp:58)
==14905==    by 0x40DA56: boost::asio::execution_context::service* boost::asio::detail::service_registry::create<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>, boost::asio::io_context>(void*) (service_registry.hpp:87)
==14905==    by 0x40C88F: boost::asio::detail::service_registry::do_use_service(boost::asio::execution_context::service::key const&, boost::asio::execution_context::service* (*)(void*), void*) (service_registry.ipp:132)
==14905==    by 0x40D86D: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>& boost::asio::detail::service_registry::use_service<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >(boost::asio::io_context&) (service_registry.hpp:39)
==14905==    by 0x40D6A0: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>& boost::asio::use_service<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >(boost::asio::io_context&) (io_context.hpp:39)
==14905==    by 0x40D596: boost::asio::basic_io_object<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>, true>::basic_io_object(boost::asio::io_context&) (basic_io_object.hpp:224)
==14905==    by 0x40D498: boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::basic_resolver(boost::asio::io_context&) (basic_resolver.hpp:101)
==14905==    by 0x40C544: Foo::Foo(boost::asio::io_context&) (foo.cpp:3)
==14905==    by 0x402D79: main (main.cpp:10)
==14905== 
==14905== Invalid write of size 1
==14905==    at 0x40672F: boost::asio::detail::scheduler::scheduler(boost::asio::execution_context&, int) (scheduler.ipp:103)
==14905==    by 0x40CBF6: boost::asio::io_context::io_context(int) (io_context.ipp:44)
==14905==    by 0x40CE22: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service_base::resolver_service_base(boost::asio::io_context&) (resolver_service_base.ipp:40)
==14905==    by 0x40DC6A: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::resolver_service(boost::asio::io_context&) (resolver_service.hpp:58)
==14905==    by 0x40DA56: boost::asio::execution_context::service* boost::asio::detail::service_registry::create<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>, boost::asio::io_context>(void*) (service_registry.hpp:87)
==14905==    by 0x40C88F: boost::asio::detail::service_registry::do_use_service(boost::asio::execution_context::service::key const&, boost::asio::execution_context::service* (*)(void*), void*) (service_registry.ipp:132)
==14905==    by 0x40D86D: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>& boost::asio::detail::service_registry::use_service<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >(boost::asio::io_context&) (service_registry.hpp:39)
==14905==    by 0x40D6A0: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>& boost::asio::use_service<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >(boost::asio::io_context&) (io_context.hpp:39)
==14905==    by 0x40D596: boost::asio::basic_io_object<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>, true>::basic_io_object(boost::asio::io_context&) (basic_io_object.hpp:224)
==14905==    by 0x40D498: boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::basic_resolver(boost::asio::io_context&) (basic_resolver.hpp:101)
==14905==    by 0x40C544: Foo::Foo(boost::asio::io_context&) (foo.cpp:3)
==14905==    by 0x402D79: main (main.cpp:10)
==14905==  Address 0x5f06111 is 1 bytes after a block of size 240 alloc'd
==14905==    at 0x4C2E94F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14905==    by 0x40CBE1: boost::asio::io_context::io_context(int) (io_context.ipp:44)
==14905==    by 0x40CE22: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service_base::resolver_service_base(boost::asio::io_context&) (resolver_service_base.ipp:40)
==14905==    by 0x40DC6A: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::resolver_service(boost::asio::io_context&) (resolver_service.hpp:58)
==14905==    by 0x40DA56: boost::asio::execution_context::service* boost::asio::detail::service_registry::create<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>, boost::asio::io_context>(void*) (service_registry.hpp:87)
==14905==    by 0x40C88F: boost::asio::detail::service_registry::do_use_service(boost::asio::execution_context::service::key const&, boost::asio::execution_context::service* (*)(void*), void*) (service_registry.ipp:132)
==14905==    by 0x40D86D: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>& boost::asio::detail::service_registry::use_service<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >(boost::asio::io_context&) (service_registry.hpp:39)
==14905==    by 0x40D6A0: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>& boost::asio::use_service<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >(boost::asio::io_context&) (io_context.hpp:39)
==14905==    by 0x40D596: boost::asio::basic_io_object<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>, true>::basic_io_object(boost::asio::io_context&) (basic_io_object.hpp:224)
==14905==    by 0x40D498: boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::basic_resolver(boost::asio::io_context&) (basic_resolver.hpp:101)
==14905==    by 0x40C544: Foo::Foo(boost::asio::io_context&) (foo.cpp:3)
==14905==    by 0x402D79: main (main.cpp:10)
==14905== 
==14905== Invalid write of size 4
==14905==    at 0x40673D: boost::asio::detail::scheduler::scheduler(boost::asio::execution_context&, int) (scheduler.ipp:103)
==14905==    by 0x40CBF6: boost::asio::io_context::io_context(int) (io_context.ipp:44)
==14905==    by 0x40CE22: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service_base::resolver_service_base(boost::asio::io_context&) (resolver_service_base.ipp:40)
==14905==    by 0x40DC6A: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::resolver_service(boost::asio::io_context&) (resolver_service.hpp:58)
==14905==    by 0x40DA56: boost::asio::execution_context::service* boost::asio::detail::service_registry::create<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>, boost::asio::io_context>(void*) (service_registry.hpp:87)
==14905==    by 0x40C88F: boost::asio::detail::service_registry::do_use_service(boost::asio::execution_context::service::key const&, boost::asio::execution_context::service* (*)(void*), void*) (service_registry.ipp:132)
==14905==    by 0x40D86D: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>& boost::asio::detail::service_registry::use_service<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >(boost::asio::io_context&) (service_registry.hpp:39)
==14905==    by 0x40D6A0: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>& boost::asio::use_service<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >(boost::asio::io_context&) (io_context.hpp:39)
==14905==    by 0x40D596: boost::asio::basic_io_object<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>, true>::basic_io_object(boost::asio::io_context&) (basic_io_object.hpp:224)
==14905==    by 0x40D498: boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::basic_resolver(boost::asio::io_context&) (basic_resolver.hpp:101)
==14905==    by 0x40C544: Foo::Foo(boost::asio::io_context&) (foo.cpp:3)
==14905==    by 0x402D79: main (main.cpp:10)
==14905==  Address 0x5f06114 is 4 bytes after a block of size 240 alloc'd
==14905==    at 0x4C2E94F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14905==    by 0x40CBE1: boost::asio::io_context::io_context(int) (io_context.ipp:44)
==14905==    by 0x40CE22: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service_base::resolver_service_base(boost::asio::io_context&) (resolver_service_base.ipp:40)
==14905==    by 0x40DC6A: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::resolver_service(boost::asio::io_context&) (resolver_service.hpp:58)
==14905==    by 0x40DA56: boost::asio::execution_context::service* boost::asio::detail::service_registry::create<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>, boost::asio::io_context>(void*) (service_registry.hpp:87)
==14905==    by 0x40C88F: boost::asio::detail::service_registry::do_use_service(boost::asio::execution_context::service::key const&, boost::asio::execution_context::service* (*)(void*), void*) (service_registry.ipp:132)
==14905==    by 0x40D86D: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>& boost::asio::detail::service_registry::use_service<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >(boost::asio::io_context&) (service_registry.hpp:39)
==14905==    by 0x40D6A0: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>& boost::asio::use_service<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >(boost::asio::io_context&) (io_context.hpp:39)
==14905==    by 0x40D596: boost::asio::basic_io_object<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>, true>::basic_io_object(boost::asio::io_context&) (basic_io_object.hpp:224)
==14905==    by 0x40D498: boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::basic_resolver(boost::asio::io_context&) (basic_resolver.hpp:101)
==14905==    by 0x40C544: Foo::Foo(boost::asio::io_context&) (foo.cpp:3)
==14905==    by 0x402D79: main (main.cpp:10)
==14905== 
@asio|1589278153.511608|0|resolver@0x1ffefff910.cancel
==14905== Invalid write of size 1
==14905==    at 0x406D20: boost::asio::detail::scheduler::stop_all_threads(boost::asio::detail::conditionally_enabled_mutex::scoped_lock&) (scheduler.ipp:543)
==14905==    by 0x406A9E: boost::asio::detail::scheduler::stop() (scheduler.ipp:257)
==14905==    by 0x40CC67: boost::asio::io_context::stop() (io_context.ipp:121)
==14905==    by 0x40CF79: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service_base::base_shutdown() (resolver_service_base.ipp:58)
==14905==    by 0x40DFD9: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::shutdown() (resolver_service.hpp:65)
==14905==    by 0x405335: boost::asio::detail::service_registry::shutdown_services() (service_registry.ipp:44)
==14905==    by 0x40568C: boost::asio::execution_context::shutdown() (execution_context.ipp:41)
==14905==    by 0x405630: boost::asio::execution_context::~execution_context() (execution_context.ipp:34)
==14905==    by 0x4070A1: boost::asio::io_context::~io_context() (io_context.ipp:55)
==14905==    by 0x402DA2: main (main.cpp:9)
==14905==  Address 0x5f06110 is 0 bytes after a block of size 240 alloc'd
==14905==    at 0x4C2E94F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14905==    by 0x40CBE1: boost::asio::io_context::io_context(int) (io_context.ipp:44)
==14905==    by 0x40CE22: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service_base::resolver_service_base(boost::asio::io_context&) (resolver_service_base.ipp:40)
==14905==    by 0x40DC6A: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::resolver_service(boost::asio::io_context&) (resolver_service.hpp:58)
==14905==    by 0x40DA56: boost::asio::execution_context::service* boost::asio::detail::service_registry::create<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>, boost::asio::io_context>(void*) (service_registry.hpp:87)
==14905==    by 0x40C88F: boost::asio::detail::service_registry::do_use_service(boost::asio::execution_context::service::key const&, boost::asio::execution_context::service* (*)(void*), void*) (service_registry.ipp:132)
==14905==    by 0x40D86D: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>& boost::asio::detail::service_registry::use_service<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >(boost::asio::io_context&) (service_registry.hpp:39)
==14905==    by 0x40D6A0: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>& boost::asio::use_service<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >(boost::asio::io_context&) (io_context.hpp:39)
==14905==    by 0x40D596: boost::asio::basic_io_object<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>, true>::basic_io_object(boost::asio::io_context&) (basic_io_object.hpp:224)
==14905==    by 0x40D498: boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::basic_resolver(boost::asio::io_context&) (basic_resolver.hpp:101)
==14905==    by 0x40C544: Foo::Foo(boost::asio::io_context&) (foo.cpp:3)
==14905==    by 0x402D79: main (main.cpp:10)
==14905== 
==14905== Invalid write of size 1
==14905==    at 0x4067E2: boost::asio::detail::scheduler::shutdown() (scheduler.ipp:111)
==14905==    by 0x405335: boost::asio::detail::service_registry::shutdown_services() (service_registry.ipp:44)
==14905==    by 0x40568C: boost::asio::execution_context::shutdown() (execution_context.ipp:41)
==14905==    by 0x405630: boost::asio::execution_context::~execution_context() (execution_context.ipp:34)
==14905==    by 0x4070A1: boost::asio::io_context::~io_context() (io_context.ipp:55)
==14905==    by 0x40D37A: boost::asio::detail::scoped_ptr<boost::asio::io_context>::reset(boost::asio::io_context*) (scoped_ptr.hpp:63)
==14905==    by 0x40CFD5: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service_base::base_shutdown() (resolver_service_base.ipp:64)
==14905==    by 0x40DFD9: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::shutdown() (resolver_service.hpp:65)
==14905==    by 0x405335: boost::asio::detail::service_registry::shutdown_services() (service_registry.ipp:44)
==14905==    by 0x40568C: boost::asio::execution_context::shutdown() (execution_context.ipp:41)
==14905==    by 0x405630: boost::asio::execution_context::~execution_context() (execution_context.ipp:34)
==14905==    by 0x4070A1: boost::asio::io_context::~io_context() (io_context.ipp:55)
==14905==  Address 0x5f06111 is 1 bytes after a block of size 240 alloc'd
==14905==    at 0x4C2E94F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14905==    by 0x40CBE1: boost::asio::io_context::io_context(int) (io_context.ipp:44)
==14905==    by 0x40CE22: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service_base::resolver_service_base(boost::asio::io_context&) (resolver_service_base.ipp:40)
==14905==    by 0x40DC6A: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::resolver_service(boost::asio::io_context&) (resolver_service.hpp:58)
==14905==    by 0x40DA56: boost::asio::execution_context::service* boost::asio::detail::service_registry::create<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>, boost::asio::io_context>(void*) (service_registry.hpp:87)
==14905==    by 0x40C88F: boost::asio::detail::service_registry::do_use_service(boost::asio::execution_context::service::key const&, boost::asio::execution_context::service* (*)(void*), void*) (service_registry.ipp:132)
==14905==    by 0x40D86D: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>& boost::asio::detail::service_registry::use_service<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >(boost::asio::io_context&) (service_registry.hpp:39)
==14905==    by 0x40D6A0: boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>& boost::asio::use_service<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >(boost::asio::io_context&) (io_context.hpp:39)
==14905==    by 0x40D596: boost::asio::basic_io_object<boost::asio::detail::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>, true>::basic_io_object(boost::asio::io_context&) (basic_io_object.hpp:224)
==14905==    by 0x40D498: boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::basic_resolver(boost::asio::io_context&) (basic_resolver.hpp:101)
==14905==    by 0x40C544: Foo::Foo(boost::asio::io_context&) (foo.cpp:3)
==14905==    by 0x402D79: main (main.cpp:10)
==14905== 
==14905== 
==14905== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14905==     in use at exit: 1 bytes in 1 blocks
==14905==   total heap usage: 18 allocs, 17 frees, 79,744 bytes allocated
==14905== 
==14905== LEAK SUMMARY:
==14905==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14905==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14905==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14905==    still reachable: 1 bytes in 1 blocks
==14905==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14905== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==14905== 
==14905== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==14905== ERROR SUMMARY: 5 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I am using g++ 8.2.1 on openSUSE Leap 15.1, valgrind 3.15.0 and boost 1.66.0 (also tested with 1.71.0).

**Some observations**

- No errors are reported without macro `BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING`.
- No errors are reported if the body of a constructor `Foo()` is in foo.h (i.e. whole code is in one compilation unit).
- No errors are reported without `resolver_` in class Foo.

**Bigger picture**
I noticed that a bit more complicated program of mine was sometimes ignoring signals (also handled by boost::asio). So I added `BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING` and it started crashing (repeatedly) and valgrind started reporting 'Invalid write' errors (followed by an error of type 'Jump to an invalid address').

**Speculations**

- Macro `BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING` revealed an error in boost::asio which causes my signals to be sometines ignored without the macro.
- Valgrind generates a false alarm.
- The most likely: my code contains an unforgivable and obvious error which I cannot see yet.

Comment: Excellent presentation. I love the minimized example. Next time, include the error messages in the text itself, so the question is self-contained and complete!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see an unforgiveable mistake.

I do see a possible ODR violation. Define `BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING` *globally* or not at all. As it stands, you have one TU that defines it, one (or more) that doesn't. This is UB.

I've seen UB due to this particular condition in my own code-base before, so I'm pretty sure this is your problem.

Comment: Spot-on. With `add_definitions(-DBOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING)` in CMakeLists.txt errors are not reported any more. The problem with ignored signals had a different cause.