# why "#define BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING 1" doesn't work as expected?

Tags: c++, boost, macros

Reference:

> https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/handler_tracking.html
> https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/handler_tracking/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp

Based on the documentation, when enabled by defining `BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING`, `Boost.Asio` writes debugging output to the standard error stream.

I made the following changes to the source code of `async_tcp_echo_server.cpp`.

```
 17 #define BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING 1
 18 using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
```

Above the `using boost::asio::ip::tcp;`, I added `#define BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING 1` and expect this will trigger the debugging track. However, it doesn't work.

```
$ g++ -std=gnu++2a -Wall -g -ggdb -Werror -I /usr/include/boost -pthread async_tcp_echo_server.cpp -o async_tcp_echo_server
$ ./async_tcp_echo_server 3333
^C
```

Instead, I removed the added macro definition from the source code and added `-DBOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING` to the command line for the compiler and now it works as expected.

```
$ g++ -std=gnu++2a -Wall -g -ggdb -Werror -I /usr/include/boost -pthread async_tcp_echo_server.cpp -o async_tcp_echo_server -DBOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING
$ ./async_tcp_echo_server 3333
@asio|1645642051.016866|0^1|in 'do_accept' (async_tcp_echo_server.cpp:95)
@asio|1645642051.016866|0*1|socket@0x7ffec2082aa8.async_accept
@asio|1645642051.017322|.1|non_blocking_accept,ec=system:11
```

From g++ online manual,

> -D name
> Predefine name as a macro, with definition 1.

**Question**> Why the macro definition within the source code doesn't work?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe try defining BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING  before `#include <boost/asio.hpp>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the commenter helpfully pointed out: you have to define the preprocessor define **before** the first inclusion of any (!) Asio header.

However, there's another reason why specifying it in your build script is **FAR** superior.

Using `BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING` breaks interface. It **must** be defined in every translation unit participating in a link or else you will have undefined behaviour (ODR violations). See e.g. [Valgrind errors from boost::asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61750073/valgrind-errors-from-boostasio/61759470#61759470)