# C++ boost::asio bad_weak_ptr when using shared_from_this

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, shared-ptr

I'm building an asynchronous socket server using **boost::asio** and getting into trouble regarding pointers.

**SocketServer.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include "SocketConnection.hpp"

#define SOCKET_PORT 8080

#define BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING 1 // Enable tracking

class SocketServer : public std::enable_shared_from_this<SocketServer>
{
private:
    boost::asio::io_context _ioc;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor* _acceptor;

    std::vector<std::weak_ptr<SocketConnection>> _registered;
    std::mutex _mutex;

public:
    SocketServer();
    ~SocketServer();
    void accept_loop();
    void register_connection(std::weak_ptr<SocketConnection> connection);
    void broadcast(std::string const &msg);
    void run();
};
```

**SocketServer.cpp**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

#include "SocketServer.hpp"


SocketServer::SocketServer()
{
    _acceptor = new boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor(_ioc, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), SOCKET_PORT));
    accept_loop();
}

SocketServer::~SocketServer()
{
    std::cout << "Server destructor" << std::endl;
}

void SocketServer::register_connection(std::weak_ptr<SocketConnection> connection)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex); // Will be released automatically
    _registered.push_back(connection);
}

void SocketServer::accept_loop()
{
    _acceptor->async_accept(
        [this](boost::system::error_code ec, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket)
        {
            std::cout << "ACCEPT LOOP " << ec << std::endl;
            if (!ec)
            {
                auto connection = std::make_shared<SocketConnection>(std::move(socket));
                std::cout << "Connection accepted from " << connection->get_remote_endpoint() << " (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
                register_connection(connection);
                connection->run();
            }

            accept_loop();
        });
}

void SocketServer::broadcast(std::string const &msg)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);

    std::vector<std::weak_ptr<SocketConnection>> active;

    for (auto &conn : _registered)
    {
        auto c = conn.lock();
        c->do_write(msg);
    }
}

void SocketServer::run()
{
    _ioc.run();
}
```

**SocketConnection.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#define MAX_BUFFER_LEN 4096

class SocketConnection : public std::enable_shared_from_this<SocketConnection>
{
private:
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket _socket;
    char read_buffer[MAX_BUFFER_LEN];
    char write_buffer[MAX_BUFFER_LEN];


public:
    SocketConnection(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket);
    ~SocketConnection();
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint get_remote_endpoint();
    void do_read();
    void on_read();
    void do_write(std::string msg);
    void on_write();
    void run();
};
```

**SocketConnection.cpp**

```
#include "SocketConnection.hpp"


SocketConnection::SocketConnection(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket)
    : _socket(std::move(socket)) // socket cannot be copied
{
  do_read();
}

SocketConnection::~SocketConnection()
{
    std::cout << "SocketConnection destructor" << std::endl;
}

boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint SocketConnection::get_remote_endpoint()
{
  return _socket.remote_endpoint();
}

void SocketConnection::do_read()
{
  std::cout << "GETTING HERE BEFORE CRASH" << std::endl;
  auto self(shared_from_this());
  std::cout << "DOES NOT GET HERE" << std::endl;

  _socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(std::ref(read_buffer), MAX_BUFFER_LEN),
                          [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
                          {
                            std::cout << "INSIDE DO_READ: " << ec << " " << ec.message() << std::endl;

                            if (!ec)
                            {
                              on_read();
                            }
                          });
}

void SocketConnection::on_read()
{
  std::string s(read_buffer);
  std::string reply = "REPLY: " + s;
  do_write(reply);
}

void SocketConnection::do_write(std::string msg)
{
  auto self(shared_from_this());

  strcpy(write_buffer, msg.c_str());

  boost::asio::async_write(_socket, boost::asio::buffer(std::ref(write_buffer), strlen(write_buffer)),
                           [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
                           {
                             std::cout << "INSIDE DO_WRITE: " << ec << std::endl;

                             if (!ec)
                             {
                               on_write();
                             }
                           });
}

void SocketConnection::on_write()
{
  std::string s(write_buffer);
}

void SocketConnection::run()
{
    std::cout << "Running" << std::endl;
}
```

I'm using Ubuntu Linux and issuing the following command:

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 8080
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

And getting the following error:

```
ACCEPT LOOP system:0
GETTING HERE BEFORE CRASH
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_weak_ptr'
  what():  bad_weak_ptr
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Why am I'm getting `bad_weak_ptr`? I think I've set correctly `class SocketConnection : public std::enable_shared_from_this<SocketConnection>` ? What am I missing?

Comment: You call `shared_from_this` from constructor - bad idea. It cannot work becuase `shared_ptr` you want to share from just doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Hum... actually from `do_read` that is called from constructor... how can I fire `do_read` as the logic starting point wihtout calling from constructor, or properly setup the aync function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out `shared_from_this()` is illegal in the constructor.

The common pattern is to have a two-step initiation for async operations. You already had it, but not doing anything, so move the `do_read()`:

```
void SocketConnection::run() {
    std::cout << "Running" << std::endl;
    do_read();
}
```

### Side Note(s)

- Don't put ODR-changing defines in some header that may not be included in all translation units:

  ```
   #define BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING 1 // Enable tracking
  ```

  See [why "#define BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING 1" doesn't work as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71242632/why-define-boost-asio-enable-handler-tracking-1-doesnt-work-as-expected/71244017#71244017) and [Valgrind errors from boost::asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61750073/valgrind-errors-from-boostasio/61759470#61759470)
- Don't [unnecessarily] use `new`/`delete`.
- the `std::ref()` is out of place.
- don't use unbound-checked `strcpy`
- don't copy at all?
- don't assume data doesn't contain embedded NUL characters
- make sure writes don't overlap, especially since all writes use the same shared buffer!
- SocketServer is `enable_shared_from_this` but never uses `shared_from_this`. Drop the unused complexity
- the mutex implies multiple threads. Consider using a strand for the connections
- `get_remote_endpoint` may throw if the connection isn't active/valid
- minimize lock duration
- consider garbage collecting expired connection
- anticipate `weak_ptr::lock()` returning `nullptr`

  ```
   void SocketServer::broadcast(std::string const& msg) {
       auto snapshot = [&] {
           std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
           return _registered;
       }();

       for (auto& conn : snapshot)
           if (auto c = conn.lock())
               c->send(msg);
   }
  ```

Addressing all of the above:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2167f37ae7a364cb)**

```
// #pragma once

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <deque>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;
static constexpr inline uint16_t SOCKET_PORT = 8080;

class SocketConnection : public std::enable_shared_from_this<SocketConnection> {
  private:
    tcp::socket             socket_;
    std::array<char, 4086>  read_buffer_;
    std::deque<std::string> outbox_;
    tcp::endpoint           endpoint_;

  public:
    SocketConnection(tcp::socket socket) //
        : socket_(std::move(socket))
        , endpoint_(socket_.remote_endpoint()) {
    }

    tcp::endpoint get_remote_endpoint() {
        return endpoint_;
    }

    void send(std::string msg);
    void run();

  private:
    void do_read_loop();
    void do_write_loop();

    void on_read(std::string msg);
    void on_write(std::string msg);
};
// #pragma once

// #include "SocketConnection.hpp"

class SocketServer {
  private:
    asio::io_context _ioc;
    tcp::acceptor    _acceptor{_ioc, {{}, SOCKET_PORT}};

    using Handle = std::weak_ptr<SocketConnection>;
    std::list<Handle> _registered;
    std::mutex        _mutex;

  public:
    SocketServer();
    void accept_loop();
    void register_connection(Handle connection);
    void broadcast(std::string const& msg);
    void run();
};

// #include "SocketConnection.hpp"

void SocketConnection::send(std::string msg) {
    asio::post(socket_.get_executor(), [this, self = shared_from_this(), m = std::move(msg)]() mutable {
        // on strand
        outbox_.push_back(std::move(m));
        if (outbox_.size() == 1)
            do_write_loop();
    });
}

void SocketConnection::run() {
    std::cout << "Running" << std::endl;
    asio::post(socket_.get_executor(), //
               [self = shared_from_this()] { self->do_read_loop(); });
}

void SocketConnection::on_read(std::string msg) {
    std::cout << "on_read: " << quoted(msg) << std::endl;
    send("REPLY: " + std::move(msg));
}

void SocketConnection::do_write_loop() {
    if (outbox_.empty())
        return;

    asio::async_write( //
        socket_, asio::buffer(outbox_.front()),
        [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t /*length*/) {
            std::cout << "INSIDE DO_WRITE: " << ec.message() << std::endl;

            on_write(std::move(outbox_.front()));
            outbox_.pop_front();
            if (!ec)
                do_write_loop();

        });
}

void SocketConnection::do_read_loop() {
    socket_.async_read_some( //
        asio::buffer(read_buffer_), [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t length) {
            std::cout << "INSIDE DO_READ_LOOP: " << ec.message() << std::endl;

            if (!ec) {
                on_read({read_buffer_.data(), length});
                do_read_loop();
            }
        });
}

void SocketConnection::on_write(std::string /*s*/) {
}

#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

// #include "SocketServer.hpp"

SocketServer::SocketServer() {
    accept_loop();
}

void SocketServer::register_connection(Handle connection) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
    // garbage collect
    _registered.remove_if(std::mem_fn(&Handle::expired));
    _registered.push_back(std::move(connection));
}

void SocketServer::accept_loop() {
    _acceptor.async_accept(make_strand(_acceptor.get_executor()), [this](error_code ec, tcp::socket socket) {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " " << ec.message() << std::endl;
        if (!ec) {
            auto conn = std::make_shared<SocketConnection>(std::move(socket));
            std::cout << "Accepted from " << conn->get_remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
            register_connection(conn);
            conn->run();
        }

        accept_loop();
    });
}

void SocketServer::broadcast(std::string const& msg) {
    auto snapshot = [&] {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
        return _registered;
    }();

    for (auto& conn : snapshot)
        if (auto c = conn.lock())
            c->send(msg);
}

void SocketServer::run() {
    _ioc.run();
}

int main() {
    SocketServer ss;
    std::thread  sthread([&] { ss.run(); });

    for (int i = 1; ; ++i) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
        ss.broadcast("Ping " + std::to_string(i) + "\n");
    }

    sthread.join();
}
```

Local testing:

[image]

Comment: Added a full review + fixed demo

Comment: Thanks. Very well explained and detailed... owe you a beer...